# Limit involving greatest integer fucntion and logarithm

Tags: limits

Okay so this is a previous year's exam problem

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\log{x^n}-\lfloor x\rfloor }{\lfloor x\rfloor }$$

Okay so the ideal way to find limit would be to check separately the left hand limit and right hand limit and check if they are equal .

The logic however that my book gives is , since $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \lfloor x\rfloor$$ does not exist , therefore the above limit won't exist too.
Is this a valid line of thought ? If not , how can I check this limit directly without much fuss as this is a 1 mark problem , there must be a shorter method to be able to do it within seconds. Please let me know your logic.

Comment: You need $x\to 0^{+}$ and then $[x] =0$. So the denominator vanishes in a neighborhood of $0$ and your expression does not make sense. The reasoning in your book is incorrect. For $x\to 0^{-}$ the numerator is not defined because of the logarithm so similar argument applies.

Comment: Sir , why do I need x tending to $0^{+}$ .Actually this is a previous year JEE problem.

Comment: Question is OK. Your book solution is wrong. If we want to talk about limits as $x\to a$ the first pre-requisite is that the function under consideration must be defined in some neighborhood of $a$ except possibly at $a$.

Comment: Hmm , thought so ! What should be my attempt at solving this then ?

Comment: So are you trying to say that since the function is undefined for both $x$ tending to $0^+$ and $0^-$ , the limit of the function won't exist at this point ?

Comment: Since the function is undefined in both left and right of $0$ it does not even make sense to talk about its limit. If "limit does not exist" is given as an option choose it.

Comment: Okay good. So do I develop this a rule to check for domain first and then find the limit in the domain only ? And what if one side the function would exist and other side it would not ? Would the answer then be a one sided limit ?

Comment: To show that your book solution is wrong, the limit of $[x] $ as $x\to 0$ does not exist but the limit of $[x] - [x] $ is $0$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: Normally the check for domain is easy and rarely this will be used as a trick question. But who knows JEE can use this trick to fool students so you should check domain first and then go for right left limits.

Comment: Sir , what if in the above question , the power of $x$ , i.e. $n$ was even ? Would I get the left hand limit in that case then ?

Comment: @Tanuj: The problem is that no interval $(-\epsilon,+\epsilon)$ around $0$ is in the domain of your expression because it makes the denominator $0$ or it makes the argument of the logarithm negative. Therefore, you cannot approach $x=0$ at all.Your expression is meaningful only for $x \in [1, +\infty)$. Are you sure $x \to +\infty$ is not the case?

Comment: Yes the limit does not exist , the question is correct.

Comment: You need to correct your comment. it should be x-> 0

Comment: Tanuj, you were right. Sorry for the typo, I didn't see that. I explained all of this in a community wiki post. I hope that would explain all of this for you better than in comments.

Comment: For even $n$ you can see that as $x\to 0^{-}$ the numerator tends to $-\infty$ and denominator is $-1$ so that the result is $\infty$. But in this case also most books will say that the limit does not exist (I also prefer this convention).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=L$ means that "we are approaching $a$ by other points in the domain of $f$" and we want to show that we can make $f(x)$ as close to $L$ as we want just by approaching $x$ from points in the domain that are close enough for our purpose. This is the essence of the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.

The domain of your expression $\frac{\log(x^n)-\lfloor x \rfloor }{\lfloor x \rfloor}$ is $[1, \infty)$. Therefore, talking about $\lim_{x \to 0}$ is completely meaningless here because no neighborhood $(-\delta,+\delta)-\{0\}$ where $\delta <1$ contains any point of the domain, while for approaching $0$ you should be able to find points in the domain of $f$ for any such interval, no matter how small $\delta$ is.